# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node' Error when append to an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a list `<li>` of items from data to `<ul>`. When I do console.log, the contents returns the following:

```
<li class="nav-item col-lg-2">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apple</a>
</li>  
<li class="nav-item col-lg-2">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Banana</a>
</li>
```

so I try to append it to the `section` and it doesn't allow me with the error message: `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Apple"
},{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Banana"
}];

var section = document.createElement("ul");
section.setAttribute('class', "col-12 nav nav-tabs nav-fill");
var template = document.querySelector('#lists').innerHTML;
var contents = '';

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 contents += template.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/, data[i].name);
}

section.appendChild(contents);
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(section);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="test">
  <script type="template" id="lists">
    <li class="nav-item col-lg-2">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{name}}</a>
    </li>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You get the error because you are using a string has a parameter for appendChild. appendChild takes a Node. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp See @gaetanoM's answer for alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of **.appendChild(contents);** because what you are trying to add is an html string and not a html node.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Apple"
},{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Banana"
}];

var section = document.createElement("ul");
section.setAttribute('class', "col-12 nav nav-tabs nav-fill");
var template = document.querySelector('#lists').innerHTML;
var contents = '';

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    contents += template.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/, data[i].name);
}

section.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', contents);
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(section);
```

```html
<div class="row" id="test">
    <ul type="template" id="lists">
        <li class="nav-item col-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">{{name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.